# How to write and update by kudu API in Spark 2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kudu

I want to write and update by Kudu API. 
This is the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kudu</groupId>
  <artifactId>kudu-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kudu</groupId>
  <artifactId>kudu-spark2_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In the following code, I have no idea about `KuduContext` parameter.

My code in spark2-shell:

```
val kuduContext = new KuduContext("master:7051")
```

Also the same error in Spark 2.1 streaming:

```
import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
import org.apache.kudu.client._
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectKafka").setMaster("local[*]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream("")
messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {
   val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
   import spark.implicits._
   val bb = spark.read.options(Map("kudu.master" -> "master:7051","kudu.table" -> "table")).kudu //good 
   val kuduContext = new KuduContext("master:7051") //error
})
```

Then the error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running
>   in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set
>   spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running
>   SparkContext was created at:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)

Comment: It seems you already have an active SparkContext (since you get the configuration from `rdd.sparkContext.getConf`. Why are you creating a new one?

Comment: i run the code in spark2-shell which include sparksession by default.

Comment: If you use the spark-shell you don't need a maven dependency. Include the kudu jar when starting the shell.

Comment: i may misleading you. i have updated my question now.

Comment: You should stop making/getting a new SparkSession and KuduContext for every RDD

Comment: i need SparkSession which spark.read.json  for every RDD.

Comment: Okay, and  why can't you make that outside the `foreach`? You have SparkConf, so you don't need that `rdd.sparkContext.getConf`

Comment: @cricket_007  i need to define streaming, val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your version of Kudu to the latest one (currently 1.5.0). The `KuduContext` takes the `SparkContext` as an input parameter in later versions and that should prevent this problem.

Also, do the initial Spark initialization outside of the `foreachRDD`. In the code you provided, move both the `spark` and `kuduContext` out of the foreach. Also, you do not need to create a separate `sparkConf`, you can use the newer `SparkSession` only.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DirectKafka").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val kuduContext = new KuduContext("master:7051", spark.sparkContext)
val bb = spark.read.options(Map("kudu.master" -> "master:7051", "kudu.table" -> "table")).kudu

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream("")
messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {   
  // do something with the bb table and messages       
})
```

Comment: @ cricket_007. with kudu-spark2_2.11_1.1.0 ,seems only one parameters KuduContext(org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu)

Comment: Spark initialization inside of the foreachRDD due to spark streaming doc. out foreachRD there is val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2).

Comment: @Autumn: There should never be a need to do that kind of initialization inside a foreach. Where did yuou see it?

Comment: it's doc:https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations

Comment: @Autumn: Interesting, you learn something new everyday. Although I guess it should  only be necessary if the configuration changes between the streamed dataframes, so in most cases it should be fine on the outside. An important difference between the doc and what you used is that the `SparkSession` is not actually created in the `foreachRDD` in the docs, it is retrieving an existing session. In other words.

Comment: @Autumn: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/SqlNetworkWordCount.scala) linked from the documentation, they actual define a `SparkSessionSingleton` object that they use inside the loop.

Comment: Which is defined at the bottom of the class as just that one line

Comment: @cricket_007: Do you know if there any good reason why `SparkSessionSingleton` is created and used instead of simply using `SparkSession`? Something to do with the configuration? I.e. that `rdd.sparkContext.getConf` is used in the loop.

Comment: It's a singleton, so `getOrCreate` is only called once? I don't know why the RDD context  would be different

Comment: @cricket_007: It would only be called once. However, I thought `getOrCreate` already takes care of that, in other words, it will create the object if it doesn't exists otherwise just retrive it. It feels like it is a singleton around a singleton...

Comment: @ Shaido, thanks your patient reply. the above source is same with my code . both SparkSessionSingleton or spark is inside the loop, the error is the same whatever kuduContext inside or outside.

Comment: @Autumn: Can you try adding a secondary paramter when creating the `KuduContext`? I saw here: https://kudu.apache.org/docs/developing.html that maybe it is necessary for version 1.1.0 as well (when using Spark 2.0+). Added it to the code in the answer.

Comment: @Shaido,can't.  it'll warn when add 2 parameters. In idea, it points out "val kuduContext = new KuduContext("org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu")"

Comment: @Autumn: I see. Is updating Kudu a possibility (1.5.0 is the newest version)?

Comment: @Shaido: 1.5.0 KuduContext also need only parameter. by the way, KuduContext is discarded; in 1.5.0(i use spark2.1 and scala 2.11). now,i'm finding a API which could create, delete, or write to Kudu tables that in place of KuduContext .

Comment: @Autumn: According to https://kudu.apache.org/releases/1.5.0/docs/developing.html#_kudu_integration_with_spark there should be two paramters in version 1.5. Since the sparkContext is used for input it should (hopefully) solve the problem.

Comment: @Shaido oh yes, it's two parameters in version 1.5. thanks a lot. could you update in your answer, i would accept it.

Comment: @Shaido.  unluckily, other issues which is different from this question. so i open a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183107/kudu-client-has-already-been-closed-in-spark-streaming)